# Selenium to read the content from website

Tags: c#, selenium

I have some contents like this in a webpage.

```
 Appname       Description      Price     Part Number      Validity
 App1           some desc1     25         JH32            30
 App2           some desc2     250        PB36            180
 App2           some desc3     20         QL76            10
 App3           some desc4     50         KQ3J            30
```

My application is like after starting the app, user will enter an app name in which selenium will search for that particular appname in this site. What I want beyond this step is that:

Whatever appname I search for, selenium must retrieve the values corresponding to that fields such like selenium should retrieve the values of Price, Validity and Part Number fields. I tried selenium to retrieve the value by using attributes like classname, tagname, id etc. But all the fields have the same attribute for each of these fields, which makes selenium confusing to select the field.

Only thing I could find different is innertext which I can't use here since I can't predict what the user will give as the appname in the searchbox at the start of my application.

My sample html code, which I got once I clicked a field(price) in my site. I used firebug for this. and i am using firefox browser for selenium..

```
<td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title"><table height="100%" cellspacing="0" surl="" uis="512" cid="0x0100DFF86ACBE51BE549AA56639FCC32D7E0" ctype="Item" ms="0" csrc="" hcd="" couid="" otype="0" icon="icgen.gif||" ext="" type="" perm="0x1b03c4312ef" dref="sites/SoftwareDev/IAG/IAS/Lists/Unify Parts" url="/sites/SoftwareDev/IAG/IAS/Lists/Unify%20Parts/27_.000" id="27" ctxname="ctx1" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" class="ms-unselectedtitle"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb"><a target="_self" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/SoftwareDev/IAG/IAS/Lists/Unify%20Parts/DispForm.aspx?ID=27" onfocus="OnLink(this)">MindMeister - 251-500 Pupil License<img height="1" border="0" width="1" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." class="ms-hidden" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></a></td><td><img width="13" alt="" style="visibility:hidden" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
```

How can I achieve what I said?Any comments would be really appreciated..

Comment: Just find the row with the appname and parse the tr element?

Comment: Could you please show me a sample on how can I do that?I couldn't follow you..sorry

Comment: You have said you've tried. Well what have you tried? What code have you already run? What HTML is this being run against?

Comment: I mean how to parse the element? I have tried like finding that field with classname, id, tagname etc, which unfortunately is not unique for each..

Comment: @D.R.:Thanks for the link..But I need to read the value of a field.The document refers to clicking that link.Here in my case field value is not a link,it is just static.

What I mean by read is that selenium must get the value and store it in a variable since I have to use the same at a later point of time in my app development.

Comment: You need to help us to help you. Provide what HTML this is being run against (the entire table) **and** the **exact** code you are using currently.

Comment: @Arran: Please see my html code sample in my question..And also i am stuck at this. I could find the appname using driver.findelement(by.id(""));

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML or your code, I would assume that the table you provided is set up in an ordered `<table><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr></table>` form. Under this assumption, you could just use the code you are already using to find the appname, and then use the webdriver's Xpath/Jquery (based on which browser you're using) locating ability to find the appropriate data value by `<td>` index of the `<tr>` you found the appname element to be a child of.
When you have the element "selected", just return the label value and save it in a variable in your code.

Comment: Please see my html code sample in my question..Thanks for your reply..more comments expected...

Comment: If the user is going to enter the app name they wish to get information from, why not just store that as a varaible, concat the app name inside the String for the XPath and run it via:
driver.findelement(by.XPath(xpathString));

For picking up the data values just use the xpath to find the app name row and then use the index of each <td> in that row to target values for description and price and all that.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have to go on is the app name, then you need to do it like this:

1. Identify the WebElement which is the table cell (`td`) contains the app name.
2. Use a relative xpath to identify the next table cell along.
3. Extract the text from that table cell.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 all along the row.

Here is some simplified webdriver code to show in principle how it works:

```java
WebElement td_appname = driver.findElement.ByLinkText("MindMeister - 251-500 Pupil License");
WebElement td_appdescription = td_appname.findElement.Byxpath("./../td[2]");
String appdescription = td_appdescription.getText();
```

Here, the crucial bit is that xpath on the third line of code. That will only work on a very simple table structure (table/tbody/tr/td); but yours is a lot more complicated, so you will need to work out the appropriate relative xpath for your website's structure. I recommend using a good browser's developer tools (e.g. on firefox, use firebug and firepath) to take a good look at the DOM tree and figure out what kind of xpath you will need to go from one cell to the next.